# Pagination giving odd error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to implement pagination and here is what I have so far.

In my main controller:

```
public function showIndex()
{    
    $countries = Country::paginate(5);

    return View::make('index')->with('countries', $countries);
}
```

And in my view I'm simply doing:

```
<?php print_r($countries); ?>
```

However, that outputs an insanely long error, too long to post here in full:

> Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator Object ( [factory:protected] =>
>
> Illuminate\Pagination\Factory Object ( [request:protected] =>
>
> Illuminate\Http\Request Object ( [json:protected] => [sessionStore:protected]
>
> => [attributes] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object (
>
> [parameters:protected] => Array ( ) ) [request] =>
>
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object ( [parameters:protected]
>
> => Array ( ) ) [query] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag
>
> Object ( [parameters:protected] => Array ( ) ) [server] =>
>
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag Object ( [parameters:protected] =>
>
> Array ([HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0)
>
> Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0 [HTTP_ACCEPT] =>
>
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5 [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,
>
> deflate [HTTP_COOKIE] =>

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: how are you echo'ing `countries` in your view to display pagination ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla I'm not, I'm only doing `<?php print_r($countries) ?>` too see if the output is what I need it to be.

Comment: try `<?php echo $countries->links(); ?>` in your view

Comment: Have you determined whether the error is occurring in the view or the controller? If not, try adding `dd($countries);` to the controller method (before returning the view, obviously).

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla I get this http://i.imgur.com/doQws2A.png

Comment: @StephenLewis It's returning an unstyled page with the same error as the original post.

Comment: @user4668941, the image shows that its paginating, isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post an answer here for the sake of clarification. The "error" you're getting ***isn't an error at all.*** It is, however, insanely long because it's printing recursively the entire collection returned from the `::paginate(5)` method. If you scroll to the very bottom of this `print_r` statement, you should be able to make our your result set. For example, look for the `id` of one of your results and you should see something like `Array ([id] => 1 [column_2] => x [column_3] => y ...` where `column_N` are the names of the columns in your table.

Easiest rule of thumb when using Laravel:

**If you return a collection, use a `foreach` loop.**

And by that I mean if you use the methods `->get()` or `->paginate()`, go through your results using `@foreach($items AS $item)`.

Hope that provided some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, all I had to do was add a loop in the view to loop through the database results:

```
@foreach ($countries as $country)
    <div class="title">{{ $country->name }}</div>
@endforeach

{{ $countries->links() }}
```